# Gracefully handle errors in child processes in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, exception

I'm using node for server side processing - going through big data files, and inserting into the db.  This will be run nightly on a cron job.  In the program have several tasks that need to be accomplished.  I have set up `child_process` so that it does these distinct tasks correctly.  However, I would like to have one error handling section for the whole thing.  If any step goes wrong, I would like to have an email sent to me so that I know.  When I saw this I thought that it would catch errors in the child processes and allow me to send an email with the problem.

```
process.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("Error running Scripts")
        sendErr(err);
    });
```

However I quickly found out that this only catches errors in spawning the process, not in the actual execution.  But then I found the `uncaughtException` event, and replaced `error` in the code above with `uncaughtException`.  Unfortunately, it did not work as I would have hoped, and the code is not run, and the email is not sent.  Does anybody know how to do this, or see what i am doing wrong.  Here is my current code

```
var process = childProcess.fork(scriptName, {cwd:scriptWorkingDirectory});
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log("Error running Scripts")
    sendErr(err);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You must do `process.on('uncaughtException', ...)` in the child processes and not in the parent.

Parent can't listen to errors in child process.
You can listen in the parent to `'end'` event of the child to see if the child ended but you can't tell if it ended ok, only based on exit code.

So in child listen to the `uncaughtException` and than you can send a message from the child process to the parent process via [`subprocess.send`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback)
the parent process can than send the mail as you like.